# How to model hysteresis with matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to model an SMA wire with simulink, the phase transformation of this alloy is histeretic as described in the second chapter of this paper: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/496a/22b77f36b22eebe4a7946e06d63cf84e4e6c.pdf .

The system I need to model is

[image: system model]

I am having some trouble with implementing it, basically I need something that switch from two differents functions when the sign of the derivative of the input changes. I tried to do it with a combination of switch blocks and if statements, but every switch resets the initial condition of the ODE and I don't know how to get rid of this issue, any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you specify the initial condition when you perform a switch? Showing your code may be helpful.

Comment: I switch from a dynamic system  that model the ascending curve, to another one modeling the descending one. The "switch" resets everything every time, for example, if in the middle of the descendig curve the derivative of the input changes its sign, the ODE that model of the ascending part won't start from the last point reached in the descending part but from the preset initial condition. I'm not sure of being clear. This is the system that i need to model: http://imgur.com/a/gxGpS

Comment: You need to model this with one integrator, and have the input to the integrator change depending on T_dot.  Switching between 2 completely different implementations (each with their own integrator) as it appears you have done will lead to a discontinuous state (which is what you've described).

Comment: Did it, now it seems to be working.